# Target specific file/folder inside git repo on package.json

Tags: git, npm, dependencies, package.json

I have a `package.json` with a dependency that instead of targeting a `npm package` is using a own house repo, we have something like this:

```
"myDependency": "git+https://fantasticUrl/_git/repoName"
```

What we would like to achieve is to target an specific folder inside that repo instead of pulling the whole project. I think it should be something like this:

```
"myDependency": "git+https://fantasticUrl/_git/repoName/targetFolder"
```

But unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working.

Any tip and help is much appreciate it.

Cheers and thanks!

Comment: There's an active-ish thread in gitHub's ticket. Take a look at this: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2974

There's no solution yet though.... :(

Comment: It doesn't seem to be active anymore after NPM closed the issue. Very sad to see, this is a needed feature.